# chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: chroot

I'm following these instructions to make a debian.img in a ubuntu 18.04 on a virtual box build

1. On the PC, create a folder and generate a formatted, mountable image.
2. Install a Debian Buster linux inside the chroot environment with the debootstrap command.
3. Upload this image (debian.img) to your web server to download it later

The link to the site [here](https://webkeyapp.com/en/terminal-tutorial/)

```
mkdir -p webkey/tutorial
cd webkey/tutorial
dd if=/dev/zero of=debian.img bs=1024 count=614400
sudo mkfs.ext2 -F debian.img
sudo tune2fs -c0 debian.img
mkdir debian
sudo mount -o loop debian.img debian/
sudo debootstrap --verbose --foreign --arch armel buster debian http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian
sudo chroot debian
export LC_ALL=C
debootstrap/debootstrap --second-stage
```

I have done everything upto

```
sudo chroot debian
```

When i enter this it gives me

```
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': No such file or directory
```

I have read all the posts about chroot and this [error](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128046/chroot-failed-to-run-command-bin-bash-no-such-file-or-directory) none of these solutions does not seem to work for me. Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Thanks for your time and expertise.

Comment: Have you had a look at the second solution in your link? It seems to me to be the most likely: make sure that all of the dependencies of `/bin/bash` are mounted in the `chroot`: `sudo mount -o bind /usr debian/usr`, `sudo mount -o bind /lib debian/lib` and `sudo mount -o bind /lib64 debian/lib64`.

Comment: `echo $PATH` and `chroot` is `/usr/sbin/chroot`

Comment: I cant seem to mount with sudo mount -o bind /usr debian/usr . It say mount: debian/usr: mount point does not exist. It must be becuase that carpet is inside the debian.img maybe there is a command i can use to insert it inside the .img that I  dont know I am total noob

Comment: I had manually copy these folders to folder debian where the debian.img was and was able to run the mount chroot debian command. Thank you so much

Comment: But on the last line of code debootstrap/debootstrap  --second-stage it gives me this bash: debootstrap/debootstrap: No such file or directory. Please help me